What is the reason to map scalar to several type in gqlgen?
Does anybody know what is the reason to provide several type there?
Anyway, only top one will be used by generator to specify model field.
models:
  ID:
    model:
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.ID
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int64
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int32
  Int:
    model:
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int64
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int32
  Int64:
    model:
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int64

